# How to protect my SQL Server mdf/ldf files on the customer's PC?

Tags: sql-server

For some reason, I must save the SQL Server files (`.mdf` and `.ldf` files) on the customer's computer. But I don't want anyone to attach my database and see my data, except my application.

Do we have any way to implement this requirement?

Comment: One way is to encrypt the data in your application and store it in the database in encrypted format in each column and table. Obfuscate your application code to make it harder for someone to extract the decryption key from your application. If you work for a company, talk to your product owner/manager, security staff and architects before spending time on such requirements.

Comment: Thanks, It seems it's the only way.

Comment: Another way is to have your DB have fake tables that your application randomly populates, drops, creates etc. as a means to confuse a person reverse engineering it. C# stored procs can be used to make API calls with encrypted payload to the real database sitting your data center. Your application has the encryption keys. C# stored procs are used as a command and control center. All of this sounds over-engineering as I write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) but it is only available for Enterprise version or Standard since 2019.

Comment: thanks, it seems I can only encrypt the columns in the tables.

Comment: TDE is great. Customer with `sa` rights could get access to the data, right?

Comment: Yes, I see.
But for some reasons, I can only use the SQL SERVER EXPRESS LocalDB in my project.

Comment: @zedfoxus *sa* is not a "right" it is a login account that you can disable or drop. You can also reduce *sa* associeted privileges (the term "right" does not exists in the RDBMS litterature) by adding *sa* as a member of database reoles db_denydatareader/db_denydatawriter.